# Can I use Jenkins to test to see if a VM(server) is up and running?

Tags: java, linux, selenium, jenkins

Can I use Jenkins to test to see if a VM(server) is up and running?  We have alot of VMs(servers) with JBoss, LDAP, MySQL etc on them and I would like to know if I can somehow have Jenkins ping a server to see if the SA shut it down or something..

I was thinking of using a selenium test.  I was going to have a Maven project with a selenium java test in it to check of the server is up. but how can I tell Jenkins to run the test every hour and do you think this is the right way to go?

Comment: Don't you have monitoring tool? Why do you want to monitor with jenkin itself?

Comment: the SA has tools but sometimes the SA will shutdown a VM without telling us and it takes time to debug what is going on.. I was thinking I can have Jenkins check them all but your right.. maybe I should not

Comment: You can use some short of shell script to monitor your server using ping or checking service port.

Comment: There would be way too much overhead if you wanted to create selenium tests just to see if a server is up.  Why not create just a simple PHP or even Ajax project to request stuff from the server?  better yet, just ping?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say the simplest possible solution is to use [Site Monitor](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SiteMonitor+Plugin) plug-in.

It is simple, reliable and it also allows to reuse build status notifications, provided by your jenkins instance. The only limitation is you should have some http server up and running, but I bet you have at least default page available.

[image]

Configuration is simple:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins does not have a plugin for managing (or monitoring) VMs, AFAIK, but you can use Perl or PowerShell for that - both have a good set of tools for that.

Let that tool return error when the server is not available, and you can even use the API to boot a hosted machine.

Cheers